# What is the best way to display report without installing anything on client

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, report

I'm a newbie developer who develop a software for a company, although I am quite familiar with programming I rarely develop a software for a company, now after I join a company I started to get a problem creating a software.

I must develop a software that can be installed and updated on client computer easily, I solve this by using clickonce, then the problem arise, nearly all software I develop must have report viewer, I try using reportviewer from microsoft, but this give me more problem when installing, I try everything I found on the web to make a setup that easy to install, but I keep struggle when installing reportviewer, it keeps error on some computer although sometimes it install without error on other computer.

I need a suggestion how I can develope a program that can display a report and print it without install any other program on the client. I use C# on Visual Studio 2015, I develop WPF, and web using it.

Comment: You're going to struggle as reports in `WPF` is poor without third-party software. You could look at [Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/uk/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use nuget in your project and add the following dependencies to it

[Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime/12.0.2.2402)

[Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WinForms/)

Launch your report viewer like this:

```
var dlg = new ReportPreviewDialog();
dlg.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = "My report";
dlg.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("datasource1", data));
dlg.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("datasource2", data2));
dlg.ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourClient.TheReport.rdlc";
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

`TheReport.rdlc` is your report as resource in your project (=> Build Action: Embedded Resource). Make sure the namespace is correct or your report won't be found.

Works with WPF.

Comment: here is [a tutorial for ReportViewer 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1) it's for asp.net but the same logic applies to WPF, Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to visit this [Deploying Reports and ReportViewer Controls.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx)

If the first option doesn't works you can try this step.

1. Go to your project properties or press (Alt + Enter).
2. Click the Publish tab.
3. On the Install Mode and Settings click Application Files button.
4. Find all Microsoft.ReportViewer dlls and select the Publish status to Include/Include (Auto).
5. Click OK.

Here is some image:

[Application Files Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdv7t.png)